# Images not loading on mobile html website

Tags: html

I'm having a issue with some pictures loading on the mobile version of my website, I tried both safari and chrome and still don't know why it's not working. I checked the size of the image and they are not huge so the loading of them dosen't seem to be a problem.

Here is the code I'm using to arrange the pictures:

```html
<a href="http://inkstudents.co.uk/article/photos-from-the-royal-visit">
    <img src="http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-photos-from-the-royal-visit.png/true/x2016-06-19T20,3A13,3A49Z.pagespeed.ic.EdDYAbdtI_.webp" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
</a>
<a href="http://inkstudents.co.uk/article/brexit-a-leap-into-the-unknown">
    <img src="http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-brexit-a-leap-into-the-unknown.png/true/x2016-06-16T17,3A14,3A01Z.pagespeed.ic.oGlAi5onUW.webp" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
</a>
<a href="http://inkstudents.co.uk/article/queen-of-the-world">
    <img src="http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-queen-of-the-world.png/true/x2016-09-05T21,3A11,3A04Z.pagespeed.ic.Xc_aOS9u3N.webp" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
</a>
<a href="http://inkstudents.co.uk/article/the-oscars-are-they-out-of-touch-with-modern-society">
    <img src="http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-the-oscars-are-they-out-of-touch-with-modern-society.png/true/x2016-06-19T19,3A29,3A20Z.pagespeed.ic.9RIRL6CubX.webp" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
</a>
<a href="http://inkstudents.co.uk/article/the-queen-a-fine-investment">
    <img src="http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-the-queen-a-fine-investment.png/true/x2016-06-19T20,3A05,3A40Z.pagespeed.ic.kzZGUE6UbJ.webp" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
</a>
<div style="float: left; width: 49%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="230" data-width="465" href="https://twitter.com/INKstudents">Tweets by INKstudents</a>
    <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
<a href="http://inkstudents.co.uk/article/globetrotting-the-atmosphere">
    <img src="http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-globetrotting-the-atmosphere.png/true/x2016-06-16T09,3A04,3A13Z.pagespeed.ic.R-c2PGPfHp.webp" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
</a>
<p style="clear: both;">
```

Any help on the issue would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Remove everything after `.png` in the images URL and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

i think problems is in src Path. You have pass two path with comma(,) seprator. so image path is not Found.

try to this way...

```html
<a href="http://inkstudents.co.uk/article/photos-from-the-royal-visit">
    <img src="http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-photos-from-the-royal-visit.png/true/x2016-06-19" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
</a>
<a href="http://inkstudents.co.uk/article/brexit-a-leap-into-the-unknown">
    <img src="http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-brexit-a-leap-into-the-unknown.png/true/x2016-06-16T17" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
</a>
<a href="http://inkstudents.co.uk/article/queen-of-the-world">
    <img src="http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-queen-of-the-world.png/true/x2016-09-05T21" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
</a>
<a href="http://inkstudents.co.uk/article/the-oscars-are-they-out-of-touch-with-modern-society">
    <img src="http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-the-oscars-are-they-out-of-touch-with-modern-society.png/true/x2016-06-19T19" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
</a>
<a href="http://inkstudents.co.uk/article/the-queen-a-fine-investment">
    <img src="http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-the-queen-a-fine-investment.png/true/x2016-06-19T20" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
</a>
<div style="float: left; width: 49%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="230" data-width="465" href="https://twitter.com/INKstudents">Tweets by INKstudents</a>
</div>
<a href="http://inkstudents.co.uk/article/globetrotting-the-atmosphere">
    <img src="http://inkstudents.co.uk/image/pictureThumbnail-globetrotting-the-atmosphere.png/true/x2016-06-16T09" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
</a>
<p style="clear: both;">
    <!-- /Dropbox Daten -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing stuff after png